# Basic R routine: renaming values in a data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I hope this is the right place to ask my question: I want to replace longer male/female strings in the sex-column of my data.frame with just 'm'/'f'. How to build a wildcard-function stating "if string starts with m/f, set its values to m/f"?

Possible data:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("fem","mal"), B=c(12, 17)))
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `dat$sex <- substr(dat$sex, 1, 1)`?

Comment: if (df$A=="fem") df$A=="f"

Comment: many ways of doing it: `substring(x, 1, 1)` or use packages like `stringr` or `stringi`

Comment: Thx! substr is perfect :) Where can I find basic guidelines for data.frame editing? I will encounter several more questions, like how to change "," into "." in one column of my dataframe..

Comment: If you are importing data into R, checking the arguments of the importing function might save lots of time.

Comment: The import-code is more than 200 lines strong. I first use a basic import-script from my panel provider to get all the labels and stuff. In this complicated case, I think, it's best that I adjust my data after this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$A <- substring(df$A, 1, 1)
df
#   A  B
# 1 f 12
# 2 m 17
```

Comment: I guess the problem is wider than th OP is currently showing. If you have other string than "fem" and "mal", it will fail.

Comment: Any other string that does not start with letters "m" or "f" you mean

Comment: In fact I had wider strings (in another language) and the code worked as to reduce the string to its initial letter. Which I was looking for :)

Comment: @Mac  Better to be more specific when asking a question, thank you.

Comment: @Mac, your question got a bit unclear when you stated your `if` statement. It can be interpreted as  "there are also strings that do not begin with m or f"

Comment: Ah ok. I only had those two strings (removed all NA in advance), so the solutions works great for me.